# Is possible for a menu item to receive an OnClick event even when it's not enabled?

Tags: delphi, event-handling, controls, mouseevent, vcl

I'm trying to enable an Administrator to enable/disable menu items in the main menu of my Application by Ctrl+Clicking them. To do that I've injected the TMenuItem class in my main form with a custom version and overridden the Click virtual method, like so:

```
uses
  Forms, Menus;

type
  TMenuItem = class(Menus.TMenuItem)
  public
    ControlActivationState: Boolean;
    procedure Click; override;
  end;

  TMyMainForm = class(TForm)

...

procedure TMenuItem.Click;
begin
  if ControlActivationState and IsKeyPressed(VK_CONTROL) then
    Self.Enabled := not Self.Enabled
  else
    inherited;
end;
```

It works, but only for the top level menu. 
Why the top level menu items receives OnClick events even when they are disabled and the other menu items don't?
Is there a way to make the child menu items receive those events too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The top level `OnClick` event is triggered by receipt of a `WM_INITMENUPOPUP` message. That message is sent even when the top level item is disabled. I'm not sure why it is sent in that scenario, but it is. And the same is true for a sub-item that has children.

However, for a sub-item without children, the `OnClick` is triggered by a `WM_COMMAND` message. But the system never even sends the message if the menu item is disabled.

What you are attempting to do cannot be readily done. The only way I can see you doing it is to handle the raw mouse and keyboard events. Personally, I would not contemplate doing so.

Comment: I'm a bit suspicious about the reason for WM_INITMENUPOPUP is sent for a disabled top menu, as the menu does not in fact popup. But I don't have any better explanation..

Comment: @SertacAkyuz The docs say: *Sent when a drop-down menu or submenu is about to become active. This allows an application to modify the menu before it is displayed, without changing the entire menu.*

Comment: Contrary to the documentation, the message is sent even when the drop-down is *not* about to become active for a disabled top item.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz I don't follow that.

Comment: I don't mean to be cryptic. It's just that, clicking on a disabled top item does not cause its menu to drop down, hence the menu is not activated, but the message is sent anyway.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz OK, I see. I guess it's up to the app to decide whether or not to show the menu. Perhaps the default behaviour (DefWindowProc) would should the menu.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz Oh well. We can but speculate.

Answer (score 2):

TMenuItem is a TComponent, i.e. it's not a windowed control and it doesn't have classical events. Instead, click events which happen on a real windowed control are delegated to a TMenuItem instance. I don't know which window control is the *real* host for events but even if I did I think it would be hard to determine which TMenuItem corresponds to the actual click point.

My advice is to make a dedicated window for menu editing with a tree control which generically populates its items at runtime based on the actual menu layout, and then provide enable/disable for the *tree nodes* which reflect on the corresponding menu items. You can then save/load menuitem list, etc. This should be much cleaner and easier then diving into the murky depths of VCL and figuring out (and overriding) how events are propagated from 'real' controls to design-time representations called `TComponent`s...

Comment: Your first paragraph makes no sense. Refer to David's answer for how menu item clicks are generated.

Comment: My point was that you cannot detect clicks given a TMenuItem instance alone, since it's a TComponent and it doesn't recieve windows messages directly.

Answer (score 0):

**In fact, you are trying to do it the hard way...**

The easy solution to your problem would be to override the `OnDrawItem()` method of your `TMenuItem` to display it like it was disabled, and handle the `OnClick` event alternatively.

(Do not forget to set the `.OwnerDraw` property of the menu to make this solution work.)

Edit:

According to the Delphi help using the `OnAdvancedDrawItem` event makes it more easy because it provides intormation about the menuitem itself.

Comment: Can't be harder that drawing an accurately themed control

Comment: It **is** harder. If you want to catch the messages of a disabled menuitem you have to retrieve the handle of the windows menu item and override its functionality. If you want to draw an inactive menuitem, you have to set `Canvas.Font.Color` to clInactiveCaption.

Comment: Drawing an accurately themed menu item is hard. If it was easy then Emba would have been able to do it correctly. This is the reason why my apps don't use the buggy Emba code and let the system draw the themed menu. The system gets it right.

Comment: As a compromise, one could use this trick iff in admin mode. I.e. the admin and only the admin would have to see the ugly non standard items.

Comment: That was the plan @Uri

Comment: I didn't use your "solution" @mg30rg, what I meant on my comment to @ Uli was that only an Admin would see the modified menu. I used @ Boris' suggestion actually (+1 for him), but I still decided to accept @ David's answer because I think it's the best answer for the question.